# How to add a HTML attribute from an aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I need to change the width of this element dynamically. So I want to add an width="" attribute from an aspx.cs file. How can I do that?

```
<MyControl:Graph id="Graph1" runat="server" Height="510px"></MyControl:Graph>
```

Comment: Bot sure what your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Graph1.Width = 500;` will probably suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If your control inherits from WebControl it will have a property called Attributes. 
You can enter:

```
Graph1.Attributes["height"] = "510"
```

Remember that the `width` or `height` attributes in HTML do not contain unit information, it's just a simple integer.
If your are looking for a css inplementation use:

```
Graph1.Style["height"] = "510px"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Graph1.Properties["width"]="500px";
```

Comment: It says "MyControl:Graph does not contain a definition for Properties .."