# Creating HTML tags dynamically in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I add HTML tags to aspx file from the code-behind?

When I create new object

```
Graph MyChart = new Graph();
```

I want it add a tag for this object

```
<Graph id="MyChart" runat="server" Height="500px"></Graph>
```

What is the solution for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464921/how-to-add-a-html-attribute-from-an-aspx-cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Not sure if we are talking about a .NET control or HTML on the fly, I give examples of both.*

This will add it to the end of the page, but I suggest you use a [`PlaceHolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) to control where it gets added:

```
Graph MyChart = new Graph();
MyChart.ID = "MyChart";
Page.Controls.Add(MyChart);

//genericcontrol example
HtmlGenericControl NewControl = new HtmlGenericControl("graph");

// Set the properties of the new HtmlGenericControl control.
NewControl.ID = "MyGraph";
Page.Controls.Add(NewControl);
```

**[`PlaceHolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) example:**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <h3>PlaceHolder Example</h3>
      <asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" 
           runat="server"/>
   </form>

  protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Graph MyChart = new Graph();
     MyChart.ID = "MyChart";
     PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MyChart);

    //genericcontrol example
    HtmlGenericControl NewControl = new HtmlGenericControl("graph");

    // Set the properties of the new HtmlGenericControl control.
    NewControl.ID = "MyGraph";
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(NewControl);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to add more attributes like runat="server" Height="510px" ..?

Comment: runat="server" is automatic with server side .net controls, any public property can be assessed like the ClientID above, HTML attributes can be added like this: MyChart.Attributes.Add("style","height:510px");

Comment: There is an error on the line   MyChart.ClientID = "MyChart";
"cannot be assinged to - it is read only".  Could you please help about this.